In C++, Is there a way to make one parameter accept two different data types?
Let's say I have 3 different Class. Notice: X and Y is different data structure.
(File A)
template <typename T>
class Base : public Base2<T> {

    void doSomething(){}

};

(File B)
class Child1 : public Base<X> {};

(File C)
class Child2 : public Base <Y> {};

(File D)
// do some include first

struct TestStruct{
    using MyFunction = std::function<void(
    Datatype /* A parameter that can accept both data type: Child1 and Child2*/,
    std::string
    )>
};

TestStruct::MyFunction func1 = [](
DataType obj,
std::string s
) -> void {
obj.doSomething();
};

// After we define func1(), I want to do below stuff.

Child1 child1Obj;
func1(child1Obj);

Child2 child2Obj;
func1(Child2Obj);


My questions is: how to make a single parameter accept two different data types in the same time? Try to search it on ChatGPT already, they suggest std::any, but it seems like this is not a correct answer.
I was thinking something like this:
struct TestStruct{
    template <typename Z>
    using MyFunction = std::function<void(
    Datatype<Z> /* A parameter that can accept both data type: Child1 and Child2*/
    )>
};

But I don't believe template can fix my problem. My requirement kind of over what template can serve.
I know my requirement is kind of weird, like you may ask why create a struct and define a function with using within a struct.. But that is what it is... sorry for that part...
I also try just make that parameter a Base type. But that doesn't work for me. Because you may notice class Child1 inherit from Base<X>, and class Child2 inherit from Base<Y>, which X and Y is different data structure in my case.
struct TestStruct{
    using MyFunction = std::function<void(
    Base /* A parameter that can accept both data type: Child1 and Child2*/,
    std::string
    )>
};

Update
Here is detailed situation I'm in.
File A, B, and C is a production code. File D is a unit test file.
Recently I add new function called doSomething2() in File A. As you noticed, because Child1 and Child2 both inherit from Base; thus, Child1 and Child2 can invoke doSomething2() for sure.
As mentioned, file D is a unit test file. Hence file D has existed code for testing doSomething() with Child1 and Child2.
In File D there are some existed code like this:
TEST(){
Child1 obj1;
Child2 obj2;

obj1.doSomething();
obj2.doSomething();

EXPECT(...);
}

I want to use the feature of GTest that we can have a parameterized unit test. This is a ideal code, I want to achieve:
struct TestStruct{
    using MyFunction = std::function<void(
    Datatype /* A parameter that can accept both data type: Child1 and Child2*/,
    std::string
    )>
    
    const MyFunction myFunc;
};

TEST_P(){
Child1 obj1;
Child2 obj2;
const auto& fn = GetParam().myFunc;

myFunc(obj1);
myFunc(obj2);

EXPECT(...);
}

TestStruct::MyFunction func1 = [](
DataType obj,
std::string s
) -> void {
obj.doSomething();
};

TestStruct::MyFunction func2 = [](
DataType obj,
std::string s
) -> void {
obj.doSomething2();
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
...
...
Values(
TestStruct{func1},
TestStruct{func2}
)
);

With a parameterized feature that GTest brings, we can test our new function doSomething2() without copy-pasting the existed unit test. Like this:
TEST(){
Child1 obj1;
Child2 obj2;

obj1.doSomething();
obj2.doSomething();

EXPECT(...);

obj1.doSomething2();
obj2.doSomething2();

EXPECT(...);
}

doSomething2() is a new version of doSomething(), I'm going to deprecate doSomething() in the future but not now. And I also want to test doSomething2() to make sure it will generate same result as doSomething().
By using this way, you may notice that we are easy to scale the unit test if we need.

Overloading? Template specialization? Just a plain templated function, no specialization?

std::variant or std::any?

If you want to restrict the type to any type that is derived from a Base<X> where X is some unknown type, then the keyword you should look for is SFINAE or after C++20, requires. Also better not mention ChatGPT in your post. It's considered noise and will make your post less well perceived.

I'm not looking for overloading. I don't what to change any stuff in file A, B and C. My understanding of template is: we can make the parameter accept Child1 type or Child2 type. But can't accept them in same time in a single parameter.

Thanks for the comment, let me do some research for keyword requires and variant

Having a using inside a struct is not weird (a struct is a class, just with all the members public by default). And using is a type alias valid within the context of that struct.

What happens if you in the future want a Child3? Why not something like template <typename C> void func1(Base<C>& c) { c.doSomething(); }? There's really no need to complicate things.

And what is the actual and underlying problem you're trying to solve like this? Please ask about that directly.

Like @Someprogrammerdude is saying, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Doing function overloading or template specialization sounds like a way more reasonable approach than some super complicated hack. A rule of thumb is, that if you find yourself having to throw together something super complicated to solve an issue, your approach to the issue is probably wrong in the first place. Don't try to reinvent the wheel...

Hi folks, I updated the post, adding more details for my situation. Hope that helps...

Btw, it's a good question what if someday I want a Child3 as well. So, I'm seeking a way  that makes parameter can accept any data type. Hence, even I have Child3 in the future, I don't have to worry about it...

C++ is a very type-static language -- the compiler always needs to know what kind of object it is dealing with. My uses of things like std::any or std::variant are extremely rare for exactly that reason: while it allows an arbitrary "thing" to be passed around, eventually, I'll need a big "if" statement or a templated cast or something similar to work with the actual data. And because of that, I just use overloads, templates, and/or inheritance ("common base class") to begin with.

If you need to treat a bunch of unrelated, yet known types in some uniform way then std::variant is your friend.

Here is an example using C++20's concepts to limit your template struct to only accept X or Z types.
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct X {};
struct Y {};
struct Z {};

// Use C++20 concepts
template<typename T>
concept XorZ = std::is_same_v<T,X> || std::is_same_v<T,Z>;

// Now restrict template to use the concept
template<XorZ T>
struct TestStruct
{
    using MyFunction = std::function<void(const T&)>;
};


int main()
{
    TestStruct<X>::MyFunction fnX;
    //TestStruct<Y>::MyFunction fnY; <== this correctly does not compile
    TestStruct<Z>::MyFunction fnZ;
}

